# How to focus on one Column of Filter Row in winform janus grid

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, janus, gridex

I have a janus grid version3.5 in a Win Form.
How to set focus on a column in Filter Row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GridEXRow FRow = grdTest.FilterRow;
if (FRow != null)
{
  grdTest.Row = FRow.RowIndex;
  grdTest.Col = grdTest.RootTable.Columns["ColumnName"].Index
}
```

If you want to filter the grid with any specific value then :

```
grdTest.Row = grdTest.FilterRow.Position;
grdTest.SetValue("ColumnName", "FilterValue");
```

Comment: very thanks ,i want when focus gone on filter , user can type her value

Comment: @hasankahrizi Go to the GridEx properties and then set the column FilterEditType = TextBox

Comment: this propertis was set but when focus gone can not type any values

Comment: but need grdTest.Focus(); after yor code  please edit this @makesh-arinha-valappil